# Change one node color in d3

Tags: d3.js

Is there a way to change color of a node or link directly, instead of iterating on all the nodes or links.

I know the id of the node or link.

```
    node.select("circle").style("fill", function (o) {
        if(o.id == source || o.id == target ) {
            return PATH_COLOR;
        }
        return d3.select(this).style("fill");
    });
```

Comment: Did you check the answers? Its a surprise that both answers didn't work for you. Just eager to know why it didn't worked. Can you please add the possible values of `source` and `target` in your code?

Comment: source and target will be the id if the d3 nodes. One of the answers should work for me. I will test it and update it. oops i did not rate those answers that way :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know the id of an svg element, then you can directly apply any css to it. Say you have a `circle` with the id "`one`"

```
<circle id="one" cx="10" cy="20" r="10"></circle>
```

Then you can simply do this,

```
d3.select('#one').style('fill','red');
```

Answer (score 4):

Apply the styles as shown below. The new fill color will be applied only for the nodes with id `source` and id `target`.

```
 d3.select("#"+source).style("fill", PATH_COLOR);
 d3.select("#"+target).style("fill", PATH_COLOR);
```